# Alternatives to WalletConnect on React native - to connect MetaMask blockchain wallet to React native app

Tags: metamask, wallets, dapps, dapp-development

I’m building a blockchain app on react native, and working with the WalletConnect package to connect a MetaMask/CoinBase wallet to my app, this has proven very challenge due to inconsistent documentation and dependency issues.

Is WalletConnect the best solution on react native, or is there a better solution anyone can recommend. (Have done research but haven’t found concrete answer)

Thanks!

Have done research but haven’t found concrete answer for better alternatives to WalletConnect on react native.